# JPA and JSON serialization problems

Tags: java, json, jpa, jackson

Help solve the problem.
I have 2 entity classes:

1.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "topic")
public class Topic {
@Id
@Column(name = "topic_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "system_id")
private int systemId;
@Column(name = "topic_name")
private String name;
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "topic", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Faq> faqList;
// getters and setters
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Topic{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", systemId=" + systemId +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", faqList=" + faqList +
            '}';
}
}
```

2.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "faq")
public class Faq {
@Id
@Column(name = "faq_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(name = "question")
private String question;
@Column(name = "answer")
private String answer;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "topic_id")
@JsonIgnore
private Topic topic;
//getters and setters     
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Faq{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", question='" + question + '\'' +
            ", answer='" + answer + '\'' +
            ", topicId=" + topic.getId() +
            '}';
}
```

}

I was forced to in toString method write to console only topic.id, because getting an error "StackOverflow". A similar situation with serialisation to JSON (jackson converter), therefore I used @JsonIgnore annotation. And all was okay. But there is a problem: when i send JSON object from controller.js `{topic: {id: "1"}, question: "test", answer: "test"}` to the server

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/faqs")
@ResponseBody
public Message editFaq(@RequestBody Faq faq) {
    System.out.println(faq);

    Message message = new Message("ok");
    return message;
}
```

in System.out I got NullPointerException. I think that is because @JsonIgnore, when i try get faq.toString (topic.getId()) I got exception. How can I solve this problem?

I solved this, adding path variable to the post:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/faqs/{topicId}")
...
Topic topic = new Topic();
topic.setId(topicId);
faq.setTopic(topic);
```

But this is spike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The StackOverflow error is because of the circular dependency between Topic and Faq. Best to avoid those.

I would also avoid the same class being used in both database and HTTP components such as REST or SOAP endpoints. A change to the database class will be immediately reflected in the structure of the data between client and server - and in the case of SOAP will likely result in a broken client as the interface will have changed. Instead, in your REST or SOAP component write a similar sounding class (`FaqVersion1`, `TopicVersion1`) that mirrors the fields of the database but only those fields you want public. Accept this class as a parameter in your methods (`editFaq`) and map the content to an instance of your database class (`Faq`). This cleanly separates your database code from your external interfaces (Web).

As a result your Web interface class (`FaqVersion1`) representing a `Faq` might have a field called `topicId` which is a simple `String` or `int` reference to the `Topic` it belongs to. Your application can then be held responsible for accepting a `FaqVersion1`, spotting the `topicId` and internally creating a `Faq` pointing at the real `Topic`.

Sounds simple doesn't it? It actually is once you hide the database behind your main application and ensure your web component is independent. This separation is seriously good for the health of your application moving forwards.

Comment: Thanks. This is one way of solving. If I have a lot of classes, wouldn't that be a big load on the application?

Comment: Not really. You also modularise the application using Maven if you are concerned about IDE responsiveness but certainly at runtime you should not be concerned. More of a concern is the brittleness of seeing a new field in the database magically appear in the public API despite it needing to be private.

Comment: You're right. Do you use for converting one class to another some easy tool? What can you advise?

Comment: You could write something based on reflection. That is, a mapping class that accepts the public class and the private class, and maps data between the two based on field names and types found common to both. It would need to recurse. This is how a mapping tool like Morphia works except instead of a private class it has to build a JSON document for storage purposes, and similarly Hibernate/etc maps fields of a class into SQL. Not commonly found as a mapping tool between public and private class types though, I admit.

Comment: Thanks for help. I chose Dozer and Spring ConversionService. Created class mapping as I need and use converting in daoService class.